# python mock return value not correct

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to test python mock but my results are not as expected, when I pring the return value it shows the mock object and not the actual result.

```
import mock
import unittest
import constants
import requests


class GetAddr():
    def __init__(self,name=''):        
        self.name = name

    def call_api(self):
        incr = 1
        self.no_of_calls(incr)
        r = requests.get('http://test.com')
        return r.text

    def no_of_calls(self,incr):
        counter = incr + 1
        return counter

class TestGetAddr(unittest.TestCase):
    maxDiff = None

    def test_case_1(self):                    
        self.getaddr = mock.MagicMock(GetAddr(name='John'))
        self.getaddr.return_value = {
        'return_code':200,
        'text':'CA, USA'
        }
        print self.getaddr.call_api()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:-

```
<MagicMock name='mock.call_api()' id='4526569232'>
```

Expected result: - To print the dictionary

```
{
        'return_code':200,
        'text':'CA, USA'
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small mistake and set up a `return_value` on the object, not on the `call_api` method.

Here is a fixed version:

```
class TestGetAddr(unittest.TestCase):
    maxDiff = None

    def test_case_1(self):                    
        self.getaddr = mock.MagicMock(GetAddr(name='John'))
        self.getaddr.call_api.return_value = {  # <-- notice call_api here
        'return_code':200,
        'text':'CA, USA'
        }
        print self.getaddr.call_api()
```

Output:

```
{'text': 'CA, USA', 'return_code': 200}
```

**Updated**:
As @jonrsharpe figured out there is another issue with these tests - they test nothing as I mocked the actual method that has to be tested.

If we consider current example we want to mock `requests` here, not the `call_api` method to do actual unit testing. Please pay attention to assertions and setting up a mock in the updated version:

```
class TestGetAddr(unittest.TestCase):
    maxDiff = None

    @mock.patch('requests.get')
    def test_case_1(self, requests_get_mock):
        expected_result = 'test.com has been called'
        response = mock.MagicMock()
        response.text = expected_result
        requests_get_mock.return_value = response

        instance = GetAddr(name='John')
        result = instance.call_api()

        self.assertEquals(result, expected_result)
```

Comment: You missed the broader problem that their test case makes *absolutely no sense*, because they've mocked out the code that's supposedly under test; as a result, they're [still stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47621235/3001761). Despite the name of the class, this **does not** `TestGetAddr`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you very much for pointing out, I definitely missed the most important detail. The answer is updated.